# Why is my XHTML5 page causing IE's quirks mode?

Tags: internet-explorer, xhtml, quirks-mode, html

Why is my XHTML5 page causing IE's quirks mode?

Here is the doctype and such, including PHP which sends the MIME type and `<?`:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8'); ?>
<?php echo '<?';?>xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?php echo '<?';?>xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="ie-xhtml-fix.xsl"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head><meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Then ie-xhtml-fix.xsl, from http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#ie,  is:

```
<stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <template match="/">
        <copy-of select="."/>
    </template>
</stylesheet>
```

Sorry I have to ask. I can't seem to figure this out, I can't find any info about what could be causing the problem. I'm hoping for it to work in IE7 and up.

Comment: have you run the page through the W3C Validator?

Comment: ...XHTML5? There's HTML5, and XHTML1.1, but no XHTML5.

Comment: @Nightfirecat: XHTML5 means HTML5 using the XML serialization, which is [part of the draft specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-xhtml-syntax.html).

Comment: Shouldn't you be serving it as `application/xhtml+xml` rather than `application/xml`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem appears to be that your XSLT template is copying the processing instructions to the output, which means that they are parsed by IE before the doctype, and this causes IE to go into Quirks mode.

Try this XSLT instead:

```
<stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />

    <!-- Copy all the child nodes of the root -->
    <template match="/"> 
        <copy>
           <apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
         </copy>
    </template>

    <!-- For any other node, just copy everything -->
    <template match="node()|@*"> 
       <copy-of select="."/>
    </template>

    <!-- For processing instructions directly under the root, discard -->
    <template match="/processing-instruction()" />
</stylesheet>
```

Tested and working in IE6 and above.